# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'. Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, bloc, flutter-bloc

I created a brand new flutter project, I added **`bloc: ^8.0.3`** and `equatable: ^2.0.3` to `pubspec.yaml` file, I just imported `import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';` in the main file, and it gives me the above error `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart'.`

I added a cubit file and imported `import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';` and no problem happened after importing, I can summarize that `'package:bloc'` and `'flutter'` exist, but the `'flutter_bloc'` not exist, and don't know why, even I tried a lot of solutions like deleting `pubspec.lock` and `.packages` and run command `flutter pub get`, and disable `include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml`, but the problem not solved

Comment: you need to add flutter_bloc, in terminal run flutter pub add flutter_bloc

Answer (score 0):

You should also add [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package to the pubspec.yaml file which makes it easy to use blocs and cubits.
and then run `flutter pub get` to get the package.